# filling in a matrix based on rownames

Tags: r

I have a matrix which looks like the following:

```
             [,1]         [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]         [,9]       [,10]
the    0.07200378  0.173467875 -0.32174805 -0.17641919 -0.1895841  0.41491635  0.52559372  0.46668538 -0.622698039  0.07609943
dog   -0.03110763 -0.307907604 -0.51872045 -0.61390705  0.2901446 -0.30045110  0.37480375  0.43265162 -0.095877141  0.13267635
went  -0.10276563  0.006781152 -0.22007612  0.29408635 -0.5130759 -0.54109880  0.27203657 -0.10996491 -0.442054480  0.14811820
to    -0.25024018 -0.690325871  0.04050764  0.19626275  0.1937401  0.22256489 -0.28244329  0.01593702  0.357230552  0.56581933
play  -0.30871394 -0.093627274 -0.28149478  0.09634858 -0.0895794  0.40877385 -0.60633919  0.15760252  0.001222108  0.82736039
with  -0.15535758  0.103512824 -0.22533448  0.18746118  0.4194084  0.64124607 -0.03984496  0.16687895 -0.373183180 -0.58537456
his    0.56851056 -0.376888059  0.48226617  0.06921187  0.5648746 -0.20768129 -0.28356166  0.70855895  0.031217873  0.71860737
owner -0.29910484 -0.727676094 -0.29929429 -0.23175114  0.4336813  0.39667153 -0.29670753 -0.04054499 -0.041433528  0.34875186
fun    0.08032176 -0.431446284  0.15740608  0.16003107 -0.1894946  0.37010769  0.26229681 -0.22716813 -0.310652746  0.06291729
john   0.08629179  0.470551208  0.31550134  0.61767611  0.6179546 -0.01474994  0.58974983 -0.39419778 -0.689627200 -0.18293759
```

With words as the rownames and its populated with word vectors from a `word2vec` model. I also have a second matrix which looks like the following:

```
                 dog play owner went fun NA_TEXT NA_2TEXT
1750_10-K_2005     0    1     0    0   1       0        0
1800_10-K_2005     1    0     1    0   0       0        1
1923_10-K_2005     1    0     0    0   0       0        0
2135_10-K_2005     0    0     0    0   0       1        0
2488_10-K_2005     0    0     0    0   0       0        0
2491_10-K_2005     0    0     1    0   0       0        1
2969_10-K_2005     1    1     0    1   0       0        1
3133_10-K_2005     0    0     0    0   0       0        0
3197_10-K/A_2005   0    0     0    1   0       1        0
3197_10-K_2005     0    0     0    0   0       0        0
```

Which is a bag of words matrix. The rownames here are documents. I want to compute the cosine similarity between the documents based on the word embeddings matrix in the first matrix. I can average the word embedding matrix words by doing `rowMeans(wrds)` which gives:

```
>   rowMeans(wrds)
         the          dog         went           to         play         with 
 0.041831714 -0.063769466 -0.120801359  0.036905292  0.011155287  0.013941266 
         his        owner          fun         john 
 0.227511640 -0.075740768 -0.006568109  0.141621237
```

Now I would like to "join" these words up with the `docs` matrix when a word exists in the `colnames`.

Expected output (for the first few columns of the `docs` matrix):

```
                 dog         play       owner    went 
1750_10-K_2005     0         0.011        0       0  
1800_10-K_2005     -0.063    0          -0.12     0  
1923_10-K_2005     -0.063    0           0        0   
2135_10-K_2005     0         0           0        0    
2488_10-K_2005     0         0           0        0  
2491_10-K_2005     0         0          -0.075    0   
2969_10-K_2005     -0.063    -0.075      0       -0.121   
3133_10-K_2005     0         0           0        0  
3197_10-K/A_2005   0         0           0       -0.12   
3197_10-K_2005     0         0           0        0
```

Data:

```
wrds <- structure(c(0.0720037762075663, -0.031107634305954, -0.102765634655952, 
-0.250240176916122, -0.30871394276619, -0.155357576906681, 0.568510562181473, 
-0.299104837700725, 0.0803217552602291, 0.0862917900085449, 0.173467874526978, 
-0.307907603681087, 0.00678115151822567, -0.690325871109962, 
-0.0936272740364075, 0.103512823581696, -0.376888059079647, -0.727676093578339, 
-0.43144628405571, 0.470551207661629, -0.321748048067093, -0.51872044801712, 
-0.220076121389866, 0.0405076444149017, -0.281494781374931, -0.225334476679564, 
0.482266165316105, -0.299294285476208, 0.157406084239483, 0.315501344390213, 
-0.17641919106245, -0.613907054066658, 0.294086349196732, 0.196262747049332, 
0.0963485836982727, 0.18746118247509, 0.0692118704319, -0.231751143932343, 
0.16003106534481, 0.617676109075546, -0.189584106206894, 0.290144592523575, 
-0.513075917959213, 0.193740077316761, -0.0895793968811631, 0.419408403337002, 
0.564874619245529, 0.433681339025497, -0.189494623802602, 0.617954611778259, 
0.414916351437569, -0.300451099872589, -0.541098803281784, 0.222564890980721, 
0.408773854374886, 0.641246065497398, -0.207681285217404, 0.396671526134014, 
0.370107688009739, -0.0147499442100525, 0.525593716651201, 0.374803751707077, 
0.272036574780941, -0.282443292438984, -0.606339186429977, -0.0398449599742889, 
-0.283561661839485, -0.296707525849342, 0.262296808883548, 0.589749827980995, 
0.466685384511948, 0.432651624083519, -0.109964912757277, 0.015937015414238, 
0.157602518796921, 0.166878946125507, 0.708558946847916, -0.0405449904501438, 
-0.227168127894402, -0.394197784364223, -0.622698038816452, -0.0958771407604218, 
-0.442054480314255, 0.357230551540852, 0.00122210755944252, -0.37318317964673, 
0.0312178730964661, -0.0414335280656815, -0.310652745887637, 
-0.689627200365067, 0.0760994255542755, 0.132676348090172, 0.148118201643229, 
0.565819330513477, 0.827360391616821, -0.585374563932419, 0.718607366085052, 
0.348751857876778, 0.0629172921180725, -0.18293759226799), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(c("the", "dog", "went", "to", "play", 
"with", "his", "owner", "fun", "john"), NULL))

docs <- structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1750_10-K_2005", "1800_10-K_2005", "1923_10-K_2005", "2135_10-K_2005", 
    "2488_10-K_2005", "2491_10-K_2005", "2969_10-K_2005", "3133_10-K_2005", 
    "3197_10-K/A_2005", "3197_10-K_2005"), c("dog", "play", "owner", 
    "went", "fun", "NA_TEXT", "NA_2TEXT")))
```

Comment: `matrix(rowMeans(wrds)[rep(colnames(docs), each = NROW(docs))], nrow(docs)) * docs`

Comment: Thanks! this works, however it is slow on the full dataset. I set the `docs` data to a sparse matrix also. The dimensions of the `wrds` matrix is `114050   300` and the dimension of the `docs` matrix is `7425   142378`. I will try to reduce the size of the `wrds` and `docs` matrix but removing some words from the corpus.